# Calculating Distance Away from a Set Number (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

This is for Google Sheets or I could also write a script for it.

I am a teacher and am trying to create a formula or function that will calculate the distance a range of test scores are away from a set number (70 -- a passing grade).

I have my data in a column as a variety of percentages. I would like the formula or function to first check the range for any values that are less than 70. Then, for the values that are less than 70 it would figure out how far each of those values are from 70 and add them all together. Finally, it will take the sum of the added values and divide by the number of values that fit the criteria (less than 70).

Any ideas on how I would accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous formulas you can use: `sumif`, `countif`, and `averageif`

But if you want a dashboard-like spreadsheet that gives you quick summaries, [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) is very useful.

Here is an [examples of using filters](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S9mObo2olNQmo7a3DxI2-ql8dGx9zEWP-BcwEe1qlds/edit?usp=sharing)

In particular, the formula is `=average(arrayformula(filter(B2:B10,B2:B10<70)-70))`, where

- `filter(B2:B10,B2:B10<70)` gives you B values that are < 70
- `filter(…) - 70` finds the difference
- `arrayformula(…)` is needed because you are working with an array
- `average(arrayformula(…))` finds the average of the array

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't know about `filter`. I ended up going with the following formula as the one you provided was returning a percentage (since the original range was in percent). This is probably inefficient but it works perfectly now. Thanks again!
`=MULTIPLY(MINUS(70%, AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(C40:C52,C40:C52 < 70%)))), 100)`